# Java doesn't recognize equal sign

Tags: java, user-interface

I have this piece of my code that doesn't work, it refuses to recognize the equal sign, it says `error: '(' or '[' expected new newframe = new frame();` with an up arrow pointing to the `=` sign.  However, even when I put in the `(` and `[`, it still doesn't work. I am unsure what to do as I've never encountered this issue before. Any type of advice would be greatly appreciated, the full code is below. I am still very new to java so forgive me if this is something simple that I missed, I couldn't find any info elsewhere that helped me really. Thank you for any help

```java
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        Container container=getContentPane();
        JLabel userLabel=new JLabel("USERNAME");
        JLabel passwordLabel=new JLabel("PASSWORD");
        JTextField userTextField=new JTextField();
        JPasswordField passwordField=new JPasswordField();
        JButton loginButton=new JButton("LOGIN");
        JButton resetButton=new JButton("RESET");
        JCheckBox showPassword=new JCheckBox("Show Password");


        LoginFrame()
        {
            setLayoutManager();
            setLocationAndSize();
            addComponentsToContainer();
        }


        public void setLayoutManager()
        {
            container.setLayout(null);
        }

        public void setLocationAndSize()
        {
            userLabel.setBounds(50,150,100,30);
            passwordLabel.setBounds(50,220,100,30);
            userTextField.setBounds(150,150,150,30);
            passwordField.setBounds(150,220,150,30);
            showPassword.setBounds(150,250,150,30);
            loginButton.setBounds(50,300,100,30);
            resetButton.setBounds(200,300,100,30);
        }


        public void addComponentsToContainer()
        {
            container.add(userLabel);
            container.add(passwordLabel);
            container.add(userTextField);
            container.add(passwordField);
            container.add(showPassword);
            container.add(loginButton);
            container.add(resetButton);
        }



        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                    String puname = userLabel.getText();
                    String ppaswd = passwordLabel.getText();
                    if(puname.equals("teacher") && ppaswd.equals("123"))
                    {
                        new newframe = new frame();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        dispose();
                    }

                else {


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                    userLabel.setText("");
                    passwordLabel.setText("");
                    userLabel.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `new newframe = new frame();` Is not valid java. You probably meant `frame newframe = new frame();` (Edit: I'm assuming that you have created a class called frame)

Comment: try JFrame frame = new JFrame("A window");

Comment: Thank you bimjhi! This fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is here.

`new newframe = new frame();`

Did you mean to do this instead?

`JFrame newframe = new JFrame();`

If so, then I will break this down into parts, just to explain what is going on.

`JFrame newframe` -- This tells java that you have a variable called `newframe` that can only be a type of JFrame. Right now, `newframe` does NOT have a value, it's just an empty box that can hold a JFrame if you give it one.

`= new JFrame();` -- This tells java that NOW you want to give the variable `newframe` a new JFrame. Remember, up until this point, `newframe` was an empty box. But this piece of code's job is to actually put a JFrame into that box.

Let us know if that solves your problem.

Comment: It looks like someone else solved the problem first. Glad to hear it! Please let us know, or make a new question if anything else comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at it, I'm pretty sure it's the way you're declaring it.

In Java, you only use the "new" keyword on the right side of the declaration.

Instead of `new newframe = new frame();`
Try the line `frame newframe = new frame();`

If that's not it, I'm not really sure. Let me know though, and I'll actually boot it up and give it a spin.

Comment: Another user named bimjhi suggested I use JFrame frame = new Jframe and it seems to have fixed my issue, it lets me compile the code correctly. Whenever I did the new newframe one, it just gives me 3 more errors. Thank you for the assistance though!

Comment: Just like OH GOD SPIDERS, I figured you had made a frame class. And we all answered within 30 seconds of each other.  I posted my answer, and then saw their comments when the page refreshed. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`new` keyword is used in Java to create an instance of a class. This instance can then be assigned to a variable that has a `type` that is compatible with the class for which the instance was created.

For example, in your code, with `new frame()` you are creating an object of type frame. You want to assign this object to a variable probably, in which case, the correct way to do that will `frame someVariable = new frame()`